# Intuition behind fibers of a morphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X,Y$ be schemes over a field $k$ and 
$f:X\rightarrow Y$ a morphism. Let us suppose that the fiber $f^{-1}(y)$ of $f$ at a point $y\in Y$ has two connected components $Z_{1},Z_{2}$.

I have read a book in which (in my opinion) the following argument is implicitly used:

This situation cannot happen if $Y$ is smooth, since $y\in f(Z_{1})\cap f(Z_{2})$ would imply that $y$ has double multiplicity in some way.

I would like to know if this holds true under certain conditions, or it is just nonsense.

Comment: It is completely false that the fibre of $f: X \rightarrow Y$ over a point cannot have two connected components if $Y$ is smooth. Example: a double cover of a smooth curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy example: let $X=Spec\left(\mathbb{K}[t,u]_{\displaystyle/(t-1)}\times\mathbb{K}[t,u]_{\displaystyle/(t+1)}\right)=Spec \mathbb{K}[t,u]_{\displaystyle/(t-1)}\coprod Spec\mathbb{K}[t,u]_{\displaystyle/(t+1)}$, let $Y=\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{K}}=Spec\mathbb{K}[t]$ and let $\varphi:X\to Y$ the morphism such that the pull-back $\varphi^{*}$ sends $f\in\mathbb{K}[t]$ in $([f(t,0)],[f(t,0)])\in\mathbb{K}[t,u]_{\displaystyle/(t-1)}\times\mathbb{K}[t,u]_{\displaystyle/(t+1)}$. By definition: every point $y$ of $Y$ is smooth, and $\varphi^{-1}(y)$ has two connected components!

Is it all clear?

Comment: Yes, thank you. However, are there any extra conditions that we could add for the result to be true?

Comment: Look up "$\mathcal O$-connectedness" and "Zariski's Main Theorem".